# how to edit Li element with dom in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

recently I learned how to add and delete Li in java script through input with dom but I want to know how I can edit that Li with dom  thank you.

Comment: Edit it how? Change the text?

Comment: Please read this tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for asking better questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .innerHTML method.

```js
let li = document.getElementById('test-li');
li.innerHTML ='New random text'
```

```html
<li id = "test-li">Test</li>
```

Hope the example helps